# Open keynote with URL reference scheme on touch of uibutton

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, properties, keynote

Is this possible? I have tried this code below but I cannot get it to compile:

```
- (IBAction)KeynoteButton:(id)sender {

    UIDocumentInteractionController *controller = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"2bm iPad presentation.key"]];
    self.controller.delegate = self;
    CGRect navRect = self.view.frame;
    [self.controller presentOptionsMenuFromRect:navRect inView:self.view animated:YES];
}

#pragma mark - UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate

//===================================================================
- (UIViewController *)documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview:(UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller
{
    return self;
}

- (UIView *)documentInteractionControllerViewForPreview:(UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller
{
    return self.view;
}

- (CGRect)documentInteractionControllerRectForPreview:(UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller
{
    return self.view.frame;
}
```

It crashes on self.controller as it is not a property.

Any ideas?

Comment: what is the super class of self?

Comment: HomeScreenViewController is the name of the UIViewController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to take out "self.". Since controller is a local variable.

Comment: After removing self it crashes on this error: 2013-02-21 19:18:00.094 2bm[2945:907] Unable to get data for URL: The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 260.)
2013-02-21 19:18:00.761 2bm[2945:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '-[UIPopoverController dealloc] reached while popover is still visible.'

Comment: NSBundle* myBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSString *path;
path = [myBundle pathForResource:@"2bm iPad presentation" ofType:@"key"];

Comment: UIDocumentInteractionController *controller = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]];

Comment: And are you sure the file "2bm iPad presentation.key" is in your bundle?

Comment: Thats got rid of one error! Just: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '-[UIPopoverController dealloc] reached while popover is still visible.'is left

Comment: On which line does that happen? Did you add a generic breakpoint on exceptions?

Comment: You probably need to declare controller as an instance variable.